# how to deal with the uneven shuffle read size in a spark job - spark2.3

Tags: apache-spark

Actually I am trying to execute a pyspark script having joins between huge tables worth 2Tb of data.
There are 800 tasks been created (because of shuffle partitions:800) for one stage. Out of which 797 tasks have almost even shuffle read size and are completed in around 50 mins. But there are 3 tasks (see tasks in running status in the image attached) for which shuffle read size is huge. These 3 tasks alone are left running for longer time after remaining tasks were executed successfully. Please see the images attached.
[image]

what are the techniques that can be implemented to distribute the shuffle read size evenly for these 3 tasks so that the performance will be improved?

Comment: Did you try repartitioning your dataframes just before joining, repartition(join_columns, 800), also why did you choose 800 for shuffle partitions?

Answer (score -1):

you have data skew issue, try to add salt to your data.